# Unable to install playwright on a Windows due to not recognizing argument

Tags: windows, powershell, playwright

I have verified on my windows that I have Powershell - the latest version installed.

When I run the command from the Playwright website :

`pwsh bin/Debug/netX/playwright.ps1 install`

I get the following error : 'argument bin/Debug/netX/playwright.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a script file. and I have been unable to find a work around. *

*to add more the error

Comment: Presumably from the page you were looking at: 
"Install required browsers by **replacing netX with the actual output folder name, e.g. net6.0**"
conclusion: your path is wrong because you didn't swap out "netX".

Comment: The comment of @PixelPlex (netx -> net6.0) is the right answer

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, so it's clear what actually solved the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [existing GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/1865) regarding this problem. To summarize the solutions listed there, here are a few things you can try:

Install the PowerShell tool:

```
dotnet tool install --global PowerShell
```

Or, Update the PowerShell tool:

```
dotnet tool update --global PowerShell
```

Or, Install [PowerShell Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2) from the Microsoft website

Then, you can try to install playwright CLI and the browsers.

```
dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Playwright.CLI
playwright install
```

If none if these solves your problem, kindly share in the comments.

Comment: Hi md. Abu Taher, I ran 'dotnet tool install --global PowerShell' successfully but the 2nd command would only work as follows: 'dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.Playwright.CLI' if I added  'playwright install' I get this output: 'unrecognized command or argument 'playwright' or if only ran 'playwright install' i got 'couldn't find project using Playwright, Ensure a project or a solution exists in 'C:\Windows\system32' do you suggest anything else? I looked at that githb link too, thanks.

Comment: i verified that my env variables for dot net are correct based on following the github thread

Comment: You seem to be running the commands in the wrong folder. Make sure to cd into your project folder before you continue.

Answer (score 1):

That code snippet you posted in your question can be found on the Playwright website on a [introduction guide](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro).

If you read the instructions carefully, it says the following at point 4 of the numbered list: "Install required browsers by replacing netX with the actual output folder name". Here, "netX" stands for the .net framework version you use for your project.

If your project targets the .net 6 framework, than your command should be:

```
pwsh bin/Debug/net6/playwright.ps1 install
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue then i fixed it by changing the command to
pwsh bin/Debug/net7.0/playwright.ps1 install

pwsh is the powershell
bin/Debug/net7.0/playwright.ps1 is the file path of that PowerShell script